# API key safety in front end app running in localhost

Tags: api, rest, web-service, react

I have been working on a front end (React) app that sends REST requests to an API end point.  I am aware that sensitive items such as API keys should not be stored in front end frameworks (like React, for example),

**BUT...**

Right now, I am just running the app from my development machine and the API keys are in one of my components so if I was to publish the app, the API keys would be easily stolen.

I was wondering what are some drawbacks and security considerations by running an app like I described *only from localhost*?

Comment: only from localhost...... *None*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's little risk, when running it locally. The app/files are only available to your browser on localhost. (assuming no malware is installed on your system)

but...
It's good to get into the habit of secure coding practices. It's easy to forget the API key is there as the application grows and commit your code and secret to a public Github repo.

If you are developing locally, it's easy enough to setup a local `.env` file with your secrets and (I believe in React you) reference it with `process.env.MY_KEY`. Good reference material [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-hide-your-api-keys-c2b952bc07e6). The file permissions should be set to your local user.

Note though that in Production you're not going to want to use the env file as the files are all visible from the client. You'll want to use some form of Key Management System to initialize the key variable. Alternatively, your app could request the key from a backend server.

Comment: "Alternatively, your app could request the key from a backend server". From Firebase e.g. if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

When running the app locally, you probably(there might be org policies beyond your control) have the power to create a safe environment to run the app.

So, you need to look at this from two main areas of concern:

- Do you trust the browser and its extensions/apps that your app is running in? If no, then this is no different than the risks of running this app on another user's machine. If yes, then you should be fine.
- Do you trust the machine that the app is running in? I hope the answer is yes because well, your source code is also on the same machine.